# destroy an instance of javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have a listener on a div "test".

```
$.("#test").on('myEvent2', function(){
    alert(1)
});
```

And I have a prototype like this:

```
var grid = function (options) {};

grid.prototype.create = function () {
    $('#test').on('myEvent1', function (data) {
        $('#test').trigger('onMyEvent2', [myData]);
    };
}
```

I make an instance from my grid prototype:

```
var a = new grid();
```

Now I create another instance from grid and assign this to privious "a" variable.

```
a =  new grid();
```

When "myEvent1"  happens, "myEvent2" fires two times.

It seems that there are both instances witch I created before while I have to have just one instance.

Is there any way to remove last instance before create new one or any other way to solve the problem.

Tanks.

Comment: Uh, you haven't called `a.create()`?

Comment: You are not calling `a.create`. If this is all your code, none of the events should fire.

Comment: This is not whole code.
The "create" method will call among the code each time a new instance is create.

Comment: every time you call `create`, you will add a new event handler on "#test" which will response one more time to your "Event1". It doesn't matter if you create another instance of class grid or not. Call `$('#test').off('myEvent1')` before `$('#test').on('myEvent1', ...`

Comment: It works. Thanks.

my last instance is destroyed when the "grid" pointer, points to another instance, but the defined event is alive yet.
Is it true?